# Can a group have a cyclical derived series?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups, derived-subgroup

Given any group $G$, one can consider its *derived series*

$$G = G^{(0)}\rhd G^{(1)}\rhd G^{(2)}\rhd\dots$$

where $G^{(k)}$ is the commutator subgroup of $G^{(k-1)}$. A group is *perfect* if $G=G^{(1)}$ and thus has constant derived series, and *solvable* if its derived series reaches the trivial group after finitely many steps.

Is it possible for a group’s derived series to be cyclical, i.e. that $G \cong G^{(n)}$ for some $n>1$ and $G\not\cong G^{(k)}$ for all positive $k<n$?

Note that such a group could not be finite, solvable, nor co-Hopfian.

Comment: I am not sure why you exclude the case $n=1$. Sure, perfect groups are one case, but we could have $G>G'$ but $G\simeq G'$. I think this occurs when $G$ is the free group on a countable set of generators.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Well, excluding the $n=1$ case makes for a more interesting question. It's like the groups where $G\cong G^3$ but $G\not\cong G^2$. I think your correct about $G$ being free on countably many generators (certainly the derived subgroup of a non-abelian fg free group is countably generated). However, if you're not correct then this provides a counter-example to the stronger statement (as if $G'$ is not infinitely generated then it is finitely generated, non-trivial, and not infinite cyclic, and so $G''\cong G$).

Comment: @ancientmathematician There’s an endofunctor on the category of groups taking a group to its commutator subgroup. I’m interested in the dynamics of this functor. I want to know if there are groups that move in cycles — your example gives another kind of fixed point aside from perfect groups. I had to edit my question initially to account for this exact example.

Comment: I am uneasy about the "move in cycles" since it is only up to isomorphism. But there seem to be several interesting questions here much beyond my paygrade.

Comment: @ancientmathematician well certainly you won't ever move in cycles in terms of actual equality except when the group is perfect. I understand the unease, but I think it's necessary for having an interesting question

Comment: Yes, though, you are right, the derived subgroup of a free group on a countable set is both a proper subgroup but countably-generated free.

Comment: Maybe try mathoverflow. Part of me thinks that finitely generated examples shouldn't exist but I don't really have an argument outside of being a commutator of some group is sort of special and having finitely generated commutator subgroup is also pretty special

Comment: Question was [asked and answered in math.overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338769/can-a-group-have-a-cyclical-derived-series/338797#338797)

Comment: I see you indicated the cross-post in Math.overflow, but forgot to do it here. Perhaps you should add a link here to the question and answer there, so that it’s not just buried in my comment.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks for the reminder! I edited the question to include the cross-post.

Comment: I've taken your comment from the start of the post and made it a CW answer (meaning I won't get any reputation for votes), which will lift the question out of the "unanswered" queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question was [asked on Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/338769/95243), and was subsequently answered in the affirmative.

(This CW answer is just to lift the question out of the "unanswered" queue.)